# Problema al tratar de compilar en Xamarin Studio en Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin-studio

Buenas, amigos estoy tratando de compilar un simpe `Hola mundo!` en Monodevelop para Windows 7 x64 (Xamarin Studio) y me tira este error

> No se encuentran los ensambldos de referencia de la version de .NET
>   Framewrk ".NETFramework.Version=v4.5". Para resolver este problema
>   instale el SDK o el Paquete de compatibilidad de esta version de .NET
>   Framework o establezca el destino de l aplicacion en una version de
>   .NET Framework para la que haya instalado el SDK o Paquete de
>   compatibilidad.
>       Tenga en cuenta que los ensamblados se resolveran desde l memoria caché global de ensambldos (GAC) y se usarán esos ensamblados en lugar
>   de los de referencia. Por tanto, es posible que el ensamblado no este
>   establecido en l version de .NET Framework de destino que tenía
>   prevista. (MSB3644)

Resulta que yo ya tengo instalado .Net Framework 4.5.2 y 4.6, ademas de el Msbuild 2013 y 2015.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mas alla que los hayas instalado.. se registraron correctamente???

Comment: He estado revisando, y al parecer no, solo tengo disponible los archivos de ensamblado de la v3.0 y v3.5 (default in windows 7). Ahora, no se como realizar el correcto registro :/

Comment: Entonces no tenes instalado los SDK para la version 4 y superior. Porque no probas instalar visual studio para que se instale?

Comment: Pues, mi disco duro es IDE de 40Gb, y solo tengo disponible 10gb horita